# What happened to Mouri in episode 219?

Tags: detective-conan

In episode 219 of *Detective Conan*, "The Gathering of the Detectives! Shinichi Kudo vs. Kaitou Kid", after Senma jumped out of the helicopter, Mouri quickly jumps out and reveals his identity as Kaito Kid. Kid saves Senma from falling.

But what happened to the real Mouri? If the Mouri in the chopper was actually Kid, where was the real Mouri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouri was left on a gas station. At the beginning of this arc, Mouri, Ran, and Conan went to a gas station and asked for the direction. That's when Kid replaced Mouri.

> [image: Last page of chapter 302]
>
> <sup>Last page of chapter 302</sup>
>
> Ran: Hey, I still have one question. Where is the real dad~?
>
> Mouri: A~~choo! (*sneeze*)
> Mouri: Fwa.. (*wake up from sleep*)