# How did Kid even know about the detectives gathering at the mansion in episode 219?

Tags: detective-conan

In episode 219 of *Detective Conan*, "The Gathering of the Detectives! Shinichi Kudo vs. Kaitou Kid", Kid was there in the gathering.

I am curious as to how Kid even knew about the detectives gathering at the mansion.

Like, did he spy on people getting the letters, or did he spy Conan?

Comment: Related, but not really answering the question: [What happened to Mouri in episode 219?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15102)